# Reducing Redundant Calculations

Tags: java, object-oriented, code-quality, efficiency

I am experiencing a dilemma. Let me explain it with two functions:

```
# Takes vector.magnitude(), vector.x, vector.y and uses it somewhere
def func1(vector, {other parameters 1}):
    pass

# Takes vector.magnitude(), vector.x, vector.y and uses it somewhere
def func2(vector, {other parameters 2}):
```

It is not uncommon that `func2` is called right after `func1` with the same `vector` variable. There is a redundant calculation for the vector magnitude, as it is calculated twice. Should the vector magnitude instead be a separate function parameter? If not, what should be changed to alleviate this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: Do you know these functions to be calculation hotspots from doing a profile?

Comment: @gnat I do not think this applies as my question is much more specific to a certain case. Also, it is not necessarily an improvement that would only improve "micro-seconds in code." In the scenario I explained, the program would be ~2x faster, assuming everything else in the functions are fairly inexpensive.

Comment: @user1118321 I am assuming that the calculations are going to be somewhat expensive and highly repeated.

Comment: How is this question related to Java?

Comment: @Hulk Sorry, I didn't specify this. I am applying this principle to Java code, even though the pseudocode is not written in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calculating the vector magnitude should be a method of the `vector` class. Then it can cache and reuse the result as necessary or advisable. Burdening higher-level logic with micro-decisions like this is bad for readability.