# ToList() vs Using default list constructor

Tags: c#, performance, collections

After reading rules of Clean Code, one of them is to use default constructor when using transferring data from one collection to other.

For example i have :

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

So what is best for performance? I know that LINQ is not effective, but is always better way to use default constructor (for this specific situation).

```
1. List<string> list = new List(dict.Keys);
```

or

```
2. List<string> list = dict.Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: And assuming you're interested in "clean" code: regardless this micro-optimization (already addressed in the answer) you should ask yourself: "Is it more clear?". When using ctor do you COPY the list or you just keep a reference? Is it true for all collections? Is it the expected behavior in ALL your classes? Is it limited to collections or is it valid to every other clsss which accepts a list as parameter?

Comment: What makes you think there is any difference at all? This post is unrelated to software engineering, as is the book referenced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> After reading rules of Clean Code, one of them is to use default constructor when using transferring data from one collection to other

A default constructor is one that either has no parameters, or where all of the parameters have default values. So:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

is using a default constructor. It is highly unlikely that any clean code advice would be suggesting you use such constructors for copying collections from one form to another.

> I know that LINQ is not effective

Really? Again I think you are using the wrong word as linq is incredibly effective. It's not always the fastest approach though, so perhaps you mean "LINQ is not always the fastest"?

> So what is best for performance?

Only you can determine this for your particular application. So grab yourself something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) and benchmark the two approaches.

As a bit of a clue though, [have a look at the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs) and you'll see that:

```
var list = dict.Keys.ToList();
```

calls the following code:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));
    }

    return source is IIListProvider<TSource> listProvider 
        ? listProvider.ToList() 
        : new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

(code slightly reformatted to fit here better) 
ie, it simply calls `new List<TSource>(source)`. So claims that linq is slow is a classic case of naively repeating an over-simplification rather than taking the time to check its validity first.

Comment: Notably there is something (presumably) *even faster* than `new List<TSource>(source)`, if the input is an `IIListProvider<TSource>` (which is an *awful* name, at least it's `internal`). It looks to be related to slicing existing `List`s