# Is an inline temporary variable recommended in a return statement?

Tags: c#

I have method a the returns something like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = repository.GetCustomers.Where(x => x.IsActive);

return customers;
```

Visual Studio tooling is suggesting an inline temporary variable:

```
return repository.GetCustomers.Where(x => x.IsActive);
```

Years ago I heard a tip on a .Net podcast (the guest I don't recall) that there are some memory/performance advantages to the first option.

The [micro-optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding) question talks about this issue in a broad context.
But is it indeed micro-optimization or style preference only?

Comment: Please give a pointer to this "authoritative source".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: There will be no performance difference for these two.  Local variables like that are free.  The JIT will do copy elimination for that.

Comment: "Visual Studio tooling is suggesting an inline temporary variable" - It is suggesting to inline the temporary variable. The temporary variable is `customers` and to inline it means replacing its only use with the initialization expression. There's no such thing as an "inline temporary variable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a local variable is good for debugging, but I would remove it when it is no longer needed for the sake of readability.

There is indeed a difference in generated IL and performance between the two, but it is infinitesimally small compared to the data-bound calls in your application. I had to iterate *billions* of times before seeing any timing difference.

Bottom line, it doesn't matter. Visual Studio (and by extension, Microsoft) only suggests that you remove the local variable [to improve readability](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/inline-temporary-variable?view=vs-2017).

This is a style preference.

Comment: +9000 checking instead of guessing

Comment: Have you check with or without Code Optimization ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the return type is also List<Customer> I would find it surprising if there were any difference in the resulting code between the two options. I would prefer the first one because it is more debug-friendly. It allows you to stop on the return statement and inspect the collection.

Comment: I like the first option too for the same reason.

Comment: possibly worth checking to see if the same IL is indeed generated

Comment: The 1st option also allows you to better document the function by giving the temp variable a good name.  This should not be necessary, as, ideally, the function already has a good name.  But, if the function has a poor or very generic name, say, to match an old API, naming the temp variable can add value.  In this example, name it `activeCustomers`.  Plus, it is nice for debugging.

Comment: @Ewan  Yeah, someone should do that.  :-P

Answer (score 4):

Since for both other answers the main advantage mentioned is 'for debugging' here's a tip: the debugger displays return values of functions, even nested ones, in both the Autos and Locals windows these days (accessible via `Debug->Windows` menu).

So if you put a breakpoint on the line `return repository.GetCustomers.Where(x => x.IsActive);` then do a single step (F10 usually), you'll get an entry with Name `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource> returned` in the watch windows where you can inspect the Value and Type just like any other variable. And in this case you'll also get an entry for what `GetCustomers` returned. Here's a screenshot for clarity:

[image]

tldr; if you've got the tooling there's really no need for using a variable. The alternative is clearer, shorter, can be used as [Expression-bodied member](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

The only other thing I can think of is that somehow want to anticipate that you're going to need the variable later and want to minimize the version control diff, but that falls under [YAGNI](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) so I wouldn't personally do that.

Comment: Definitely the debugging option way.  