# Two reversed dictionaries or one dictionary with key and value lookup?

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-smell, collections

I have situation where in the Repository class I have a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<TableName, Dictionary<EntityColumnName, SourceColumnName> map1 = new Dictionary<TableName, Dictionary<EntityColumnName, SourceColumnName> ()
```

with methods for manipulating data (Get,Save,Add etc).

Now there is a need to search by value from the inner map, not only by key (in this example `SourceColumnName`).

My question is what would be best approach here? I want to add another dictionary but with reversed data:

```
Dictionary<TableName, Dictionary<SourceColumnName, EntityColumnName> map2 = new Dictionary<TableName, Dictionary<SourceColumnName, EntityColumnName> ()
```

But the problem is memory usage, is that a waste of memory? But if I implement lookup by value, I'll lose the main advantage of dictionary.

The data stored in the dictionary is around 20 * 5k data in the inner map.
Any suggestion how to design / refactor this class would be appreciated.

EDIT1:
Micro optimisation post didn't resolved my problem. I work on project where optimisation is very important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you're looking for is generally called a '[bidirectional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map) dictionary'; I found a C# implementation in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/268545/4751173), but you're on the right track; you'll *need* two dictionaries, so memory usage *will* be higher. Whether this is worth the increase in performance you can only find out by testing and measuring.

Comment: Firstly thanks for answer. This means that 2 dictionary is good option and i will accept this answer.