# Working through the single responsibility principle (SRP) in Python when calls are expensive

Tags: python, performance, single-responsibility, methods

Some base points:

- [Python method calls are "expensive" due to its interpreted nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893139/why-is-a-function-method-call-in-python-expensive). In theory, if your code is simple enough, breaking down Python code has negative impact besides readability and reuse (*which is a big gain for developers, not so much for users*).
- The single responsibility principle (SRP) keeps code readable, is easier to test and maintain.
- The project has a special kind of background where we want readable code, tests, *and* time performance.

For instance, code like this which invokes several methods (x4) is slower than the following one which is just one.

```py
from operator import add

class Vector:
    def __init__(self,list_of_3):
        self.coordinates = list_of_3

    def move(self,movement):
        self.coordinates = list( map(add, self.coordinates, movement))
        return self.coordinates

    def revert(self):
        self.coordinates = self.coordinates[::-1]
        return self.coordinates

    def get_coordinates(self):
        return self.coordinates

## Operation with one vector
vec3 = Vector([1,2,3])
vec3.move([1,1,1])
vec3.revert()
vec3.get_coordinates()
```

In comparison to this:

```py
from operator import add

def move_and_revert_and_return(vector,movement):
    return list( map(add, vector, movement) )[::-1]

move_and_revert_and_return([1,2,3],[1,1,1])
```

If I am to parallelize something such as that, it is pretty objective I lose performance. Mind that is just an example; my project has several mini routines with math such as that - While it is much easier to work with, our profilers are disliking it.

---

**How and where do we embrace the SRP without compromising performance in Python, as its inherent implementation directly impacts it?**

Are there workarounds, like some sort of pre-processor that puts things in-line for release?

Or is Python simply poor at handling code breakdown altogether?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: For what it's worth, your two code examples *do not differ in number of responsibilities.*  The SRP is not a method counting exercise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're right, sorry for the poor example and I'll edit a better one when I have the time. In either case, readability and maintanability suffers and eventually the SRP breaks down within the codebase as we cut down on classes and their methods.

Comment: note that _function calls are expensive in any language_, though AOT compilers have the luxury of inlining

Comment: Does your object *really* have four responsibilities: move, revert, get_coordinates, and move_and_revert_and_return? or does it *really* only have the one responsibility, move_and_revert_and_return?

Comment: Use  a JITted implementation of python such as PyPy. Should mostly fix this problem.

Comment: @Eevee There's a whole lot more book keeping going on in Python than in C when you're calling a method. That said, if someone's worrying about the performance of *method calls* Python is clearly the wrong language. Most business code is limited by IO and not CPU.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you're putting anything in parallel here. The GIL in Python prevents you from running multiple threads concurrently, and the overhead of multiprocessing seems like it would drastically outweigh the cost of a few method calls.

Comment: Furthermore, OOP is not encouraged in Python. It is generally unnecessary. The primary use of classes in OOP is to enable late binding, but Python supports late binding for everything, including methods not bound to an object. Also, why are you writing your own vector logic? You should probably be using a well known, C-implemented math package like numpy or scipy or whatever provides the functionality you need. You'll get a much better performance boost using those than you will fiddling with whether methods are bound to an object or not.

Comment: @jpmc26 It is hard to explain, but we are implementing analytical solutions which aren't implemented yet, *can* be parallelized for a purpose, and *does* yield results. As for the code itself it is just a structure example (and a poor one on top of that, we do use numpy/scipy whenever we can). Overall, maybe the question should be reworded to OOP paradigm instead of SRP.

Comment: If a principle makes you write bad or inefficient code, ditch the principle. We are paid for working, performant code, not to make Uncle Bob happy.

Comment: I love Python, but frankly, if regular method calls are becoming a significant source of performance degradation, then Python simply isn't the appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> is Python simply poor at handling code breakdown altogether?

Unfortunately yes, Python is slow and there are many anecdotes about people drastically increasing performance by inlining functions and making their code ugly.

There is a work around, Cython, which is a compiled version of Python and much faster.

--Edit
I just wanted to address some of the comments and other answers. Although the thrust of them isnt perhaps python specific. but more general optimisation.

1. Don't optimise untill you have a problem and then look for bottlenecks

   Generally good advice. But the assumption is that 'normal' code is usually performant. This isn't always the case. Individual languages and frameworks each have their own idiosyncracies. In this case function calls.
2. Its only a few milliseconds, other things will be slower

   If you are running your code on a powerful desktop computer you probably don't care as long as your single user code executes in a few seconds.

   But business code tends to run for multiple users and require more than one machine to support the load. If your code runs twice as fast it means you can have twice the number of users or half the number of machines.

   If you own your machines and data centre then you generally have a big chunk of overhead in CPU power. If your code runs a bit slow, you can absorb it, at least until you need to buy a second machine.

   In these days of cloud computing where you only use exactly the compute power you require and no more, there is a direct cost for non performant code.

   Improving performance can drastically cut the main expense for a cloud based business and performance really should be front and centre.

Comment: While Robert's Answer helps cover some bases for potential misunderstandings behind doing this sort of optimization (which fits [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding) ), I feel this answers the situation a bit more directly and in-line with the Python context.

Comment: sorry its somewhat short. I don't have time to write more. But I do think Robert is wrong on this one. The best advice with python seems to be to profile _as_ you code. _Dont_ assume it will be performant and only optimise if you find a problem

Comment: @Ewan: You don't have to write the entire program first to follow my advice.  A method or two is more than sufficient to get adequate profiling.

Comment: you can also try pypy, which is a JITted python

Comment: @Ewan If you're really worried about the performance overhead of function calls, whatever you're doing is probably not suited for python. But then I really can't think of many examples there. The vast majority of business code is IO limited and the CPU heavy stuff is usually handled by calling out to native libraries (numpy, tensorflow and so on).

Comment: @Voo Unless you use a lib like PyQt that tries to do MVC and does millions of calls into your python model, as those are cheap in C++ due to inlining, which CPython doesn't do. Basically any model that assumes calls get inlined are bad for python. Even for I/O the call overhead is significant if you have a decent (10Gb/s or faster) backbone. Like older versions of python httplib wasting 30% cpu on chunked encoding.

Comment: @schlenk You think your *GUI* is noticeably slow because of the overhead of function calls in Python? I've written PyQT UIs that were perfectly performant, the method overhead wasn't anywhere near the front of my worries. Also inlining callbacks into user provided code from a library? Don't see how that would work.

Comment: @Voo Not think. Profiled it. It happens, for small models it is not an issue, but when a view does 500.000+ calls into your model to update itself, it shows in the Python version but is mostly harmless in the C++ version. And you can inline code from a library in compiled languages. Either via JIT or with something like full program optimization. Or for C++ you often have template based header only libraries that do it at compile time.

Comment: @schlenk Oh in general the techniques are well known, but for QT? Don't see how you could ever inline calls to slots in C++. Any sample that demonstrates how that would work? In any case if your view has to do 500k calls for a single update, there's almost certainly some restructuring that could help more. Only do partial redraws, make sure to limit the amount of recomputation if things change and so on.

Comment: @Voo, for example VC++ with /LTCG does "Cross-module inlining". And of course the optimization work, but python needs a lot more of those than other languages. (e.g. multiprocessing to hack around the threading, no inlining, adding a 100 MB to do fast vector stuff, etc.)

Comment: @schlenk As I already said I know all those things, I've worked on HotSpot. What I'm disputing is your claim that MSVC can inline calls to slots in QT (this is after all harder than inlining virtual calls and VS can't even do that reliably with LTCG) and that the call overhead in Python would be the reason that the PyQT code is slower..

Answer (score 50):

**Many potential performance concerns are not really a problem in practice.**  The issue you raise may be one of them.  In the vernacular, we call worrying about those problems without proof that they are actual problems *premature optimization.*

If you are writing a front-end for a web service, your performance is not going to be significantly affected by function calls, because the cost of sending data over a network far exceeds the time it takes to make a method call.

If you are writing a tight loop that refreshes a video screen sixty times a second, then it might matter.  But at that point, I claim you have larger problems if you're trying to use Python to do that, a job for which Python is probably not well-suited.

As always, the way you find out is to ***measure.*** Run a performance profiler or some timers over your code.  See if it's a real problem in practice.

---

The Single Responsibility Principle is not a law or mandate; it is a guideline or principle.  Software design is always about trade-offs; there are no absolutes.  It is not uncommon to trade off readability and/or maintainability for speed, so you may have to sacrifice SRP on the altar of performance.  But don't make that tradeoff unless you **know** you have a performance problem.

Comment: I think this was true, until we invented cloud computing. Now one of the two functions effectively costs 4 times as much as the other

Comment: @Ewan 4 times may not matter until you've measured it to be significant enough to care about.  If Foo takes 1 ms and Bar takes 4 ms that's not good.  Until you realize that transmitting the data across the network takes 200 ms.  At that point, Bar being slower doesn't matter so much.  (Just one possible example of where being X times slower doesn't make a noticeable or impactful difference, not meant to be necessarily super realistic.)

Comment: @Becuzz the difference with cloud computing is that (to generalize) you pay for the 4ms and not the 200ms

Comment: @Ewan Fair enough.  I guess it just depends on why you are trying to optimize that 3 ms away and if the cost is worth the time/effort invested.

Comment: This is not a premature optimization sadly! We are parallelizing some special calculations and so those ms are effectively multiplied by millions, and our profilers show that. As we are trying to squeeze out performance, sacrificing the SRP has become an option towards improvement, I suppose I have a good reason for ugly code or complete project translation now.

Comment: @becuzz forget about the 3ms, think about reducing your monthly bill from AWS by 75%

Comment: @Ewan If the reduction in the bill saves you $15/month but it will take a $125/hour contractor 4 hours to fix and test it, I could easily justify that not being worth a business's time to do (or at least not do right now if time to market is crucial, etc.).  There are always tradeoffs.  And what makes sense in one circumstance might not in another.

Comment: your AWS bills are very low indeed

Comment: When I get to make up numbers, they certainly are (also when I never have to deal with any of that, I honestly have no idea what some of that costs, the most I've ever looked at was the cost to spin up and run an EC2 instance, never looked at lambda, etc.).

Comment: @Ewan AWS rounds to the ceiling by batches anyways (standard is 100ms). Which means this kind of optimization only saves you anything if it consistently avoids pushing you to the next chunk.

Comment: @Delioth I assume you are referring to lambda pricing? in this case the fast function runs 100 times in 100ms and the OOP version runs 25 times. or rather the OOP version will spawn 4 lambda instances and charge you for 400ms rather than 100ms

Answer (score 2):

First, some clarifications: Python is a language. There are several different interpreters which can execute code written in the Python language. The reference implementation (CPython) is usually what is being referenced when someone talks about "Python" as if it is an implementation, but it is important to be precise when talking about performance characteristics, as they can differ wildly between implementations.

> How and where do we embrace the SRP without compromising performance in Python, as its inherent implementation directly impacts it?

**Case 1.)**
If you have pure Python code (<= Python Language version 3.5, 3.6 has "beta level support") which only relies on pure Python modules, you can embrace SRP everywhere and use PyPy to run it. PyPy (https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2019/03/pypy-v71-released-now-uses-utf-8.html) is a Python interpreter which has a Just in Time Compiler (JIT) and can remove function call overhead as long as it has sufficient time to "warm up" by tracing the executed code (a few seconds IIRC). **

If you are restricted to using the CPython interpreter, you can extract the slow functions into extensions written in C, which will be pre-compiled and not suffer from any interpreter overhead. You can still use SRP everywhere, but your code will be split between Python and C. Whether this is better or worse for maintainability than selectively abandoning SRP but sticking to only Python code depends on your team, but if you have performance critical sections of your code, it will undoubtably be faster than even the most optimized pure Python code interpreted by CPython. Many of Python's fastest mathematical libraries use this method (numpy and scipy IIRC). Which is a nice segue into Case 2...

**Case 2.)**
If you have Python code which uses C extensions (or relies on libraries which use C extensions), PyPy may or may not be useful depending on how they're written. See http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/extending.html for details, but the summary is that CFFI has minimal overhead while CTypes is slower (using it with PyPy may be even slower than CPython)

Cython (https://cython.org/) is another option which I don't have as much experience with. I mention it for the sake of completeness so my answer can "stand on its own", but don't claim any expertise. From my limited usage, it felt like I had to work harder to get the same speed improvements i could get "for free" with PyPy, and if I needed something better than PyPy, it was just as easy to write my own C extension (which has the benefit if I re-use the code elsewhere or extract part of it into a library, all my code can still run under any Python Interpreter and is not required to be run by Cython).

I'm scared of being "locked into" Cython, whereas any code written for PyPy can run under CPython as well.

** Some extra notes on PyPy in Production

Be very careful about making any choices that have the practical effect of "locking you in" to PyPy in a large codebase. Because some (very popular and useful) third party libraries do not play nice for reasons mentioned earlier, it can cause very difficult decisions later if you realize you need one of those libraries. My experience is primarily in using PyPy to speed up some (but not all) microservices which are performance sensitive in an company environment where it adds negligible complexity to our production environment (we already have multiple languages deployed, some with different major versions like 2.7 vs 3.5 running anyways).

I have found using both PyPy and CPython regularly forced me to write code which only relies on guarantees made by the language specification itself, and not on implementation details which are subject to change at any time.  You may find thinking about such details to be an extra burden, but I found it valuable in my professional development, and I think it is "healthy" for the Python ecosystem as a whole.

Comment: Yeah! I've been considering focus on C extensions for this case instead of abandoning the principle and writing wild code, the other answers gave me the impression it would be slow regardless unless I swapped from the reference interpreter - To clear it up, OOP would still be a sensible approach in your view?

Comment: with case 1 (2nd para) do you not get the same over head _calling_ the functions, even if the functions themselves are complied?

Comment: CPython is the only interpreter that is generally taken seriously. PyPy is *interesting*, but it certainly isn't seeing any kind of widespread adoption. Furthermore, it's behavior [differs](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html) from CPython, and it doesn't work with some important packages, e.g. scipy. Few sane developers would recommend PyPy for production. As such, the distinction between the language and the implementation is inconsequential in practice.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head though. There's no reason you couldn't have a better interpreter, or a compiler. It's not intrinsic to python as a language. You are just stuck with practical realities

Comment: @jpmc26 I've used PyPy in production, and recommend considering doing so to other experienced developers. It is great for microservices using https://falconframework.org/ for lightweight rest APIs (as one example).  Behavior differing because developers rely on implementation details which are NOT a guarantee of the language is not a reason to not use PyPy. It's a reason to rewrite your code. The same code may break anyway if CPython make changes to its implementation (which it is free to do as long as it still conforms to the language spec).

Comment: @lucasgcb Yes, OOP would still be a sensible approach in my view.

Comment: @ewan, functions can be inlined as part of the Just in Time Compilation process. If you directly call A, A calls 5 different functions, each of which call 3 other functions, you pay function call overhead (1 + 5 + 5 *3) = 21 times. If that all gets inlined by the JIT as part of optimizing function A, then you will only pay function cal overhead for A, which is 21 times less (the rest of the function calls disappear because the functions were inlined).

Comment: @ewan, (cont.) So if you meaning is "don't you pay the same overhead for calling A even if the JIT optimizes it?" then yes, you do. But overall function call overhead in your program is still substantially lower, which is more likely what you're worried about in any case.

Comment: @jpmc26 if you have a monolith, or even large services, you can get into trouble with PyPy not playing nice with certain libraries that you find you need only after you've written most of your code with the idea PyPy was going to make it fast, and that can be a serious problem. If you have small microservices, however, you can pick PyPy or CPython on a per-microservice basis without causing yourself any longterm headaches. Just make sure your tests run it under both interpreters and pass in both cases in case you do need to make a change later.

Comment: @StevenJackson Microservices have their own set of long term headaches. Deciding to use them categorically just to enable the use of PyPy on *some* of them is not a good design decision.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree fully. I have been working in companies that already used microservices for unrelated reasons, and in that situation I found selective usage of PyPy to have very few drawbacks with strong benefits. I would not use PyPy as a major reason to choose to use microservices in the first place. Since we already had microservices in multiple different languages, adding a new interpreter to that mix did not complicate things appreciably.

Comment: @jpmc26 I have added a new footnote to my answer to address some of the (very good) concerns you raise about using PyPy in production. You helped me realize I had some implicit assumptions based on my professional history which may not be valid for the OP, so they should be explicitly mentioned.