# Memory optimization of public methods in java

Tags: java, optimization, memory-usage

Does it optimize a program in java to declare methods private wherever they can be private or it doesn't change a thing and it's just a question of encapsulation? I was asking myself if declaring a method public was heavier than a declaring it private in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: In Java your method declarations only use a tiny bit of memory in the meta (or permanent) space.  Even if this was the case, it's irrelevant unless you have some insane number of class definitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`private` methods can never be overridden, whereas `protected` and `public` methods can be overridden.

As a consequence of this, the underlying runtime knows that for `private` methods:

- There is no need to place them in the method table
- It can invoke them using non-virtual dispatching

By contrast, `protected` and `public` methods are most likely placed into the method table, and, analysis would take place to determine whether to invoke using virtual dispatch through the method table or not.  (To err on the side of correctness, virtual dispatch would be used.  Due to dynamic class loading the method *may* potentially be overridden sometime in the future, which might require adjustment to optimistic choices.)

The above does not take into account `final` classes: methods in final classes share the above discussed qualities among all methods `private`, `protected`, and `public`.

---

But worrying about this is micro optimization.  It is very unlikely that virtual dispatch will have a meaningful effect on the performance or memory consumption of your application.

Comment: In a hot loop, it can have a _very_ noticeable impact on the performance. This is the difference between monomorphic and megamorphic calls that prevent JIT from doing method inlining and other optimizations.

Comment: @JurajMartinka: The JVM supports speculative inlining. That is, the mere use of a protected or public modifier does not make a call site megamorphic, or prevent inlining or other optimizations.

Comment: @meriton that is correct. What makes a callsite megamorphic isn't actually a number of different "subtypes" present int the program code or dependencies but what JIT observes at runtime. I was commenting on "It is very unlikely that virtual dispatch will have a meaningful effect on the performance or memory consumption of your application." which is imho false.

Answer (score 1):

Access modifiers like `private` and `public` have **no effect** on the resource requirements of a Java program. They exist largely as documentation and aids to understanding for *human* readers and writers of the code. Even when information about the status of a field or method is retained at runtime, it's likely to be stored in a bitfield-like structure, so either value takes the same amount of memory.

In short, making things `private` does not optimize computer memory (RAM) in any way. It *can*, however, be better for *human* memory, because an API with fewer visible members is easier to understand and easier to remember than an API with everything `public`.