# Best way to deal with lots of nested closures in Swift

Tags: swift-language, closures

I have some external SDK library that makes IO calls (either networking or database) in the form of blocks, like so:

```
SomeClass.doWork(success: {}, failure: {})
```

Now I need to chain about 60 different calls because we are working on data replication where each operation is distinct enough that it's not the same, but the principle is there -> all of these take a `success` and a `failure` blocks.

What is the best way to organise this spaghetti:

```
let failureBlock: () -> Void = { // something
}

SomeClass.doWork(success: { [unowned self] in
   self.runChecks(success: {
       SomeOtherClass.somethingElse(success: { 
           SomeClass.doWork(success: { [unowned self] in
              self.doMore() ///... and on and on she goes
           }, failure: failureBlock)
       }, failure: failureBlock)
    }, failure: failureBlock)
}, failure: failureBlock)
```

**Update** I am concerned with performance and memory management over legibility as my stack traces look quite ugly with lots of `thunk` and `closure` in them :/

Comment: Do you have any actual evidence that these closures are causing either a performance or memory management issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: You should look into "futures"/"promises". Swift has quite a few libraries that offer them, like `Combine` (which is built in by Apple), RxSwift, and PromiseKit

Answer (score 0):

You can store closures in a variable.

```
Let task60 = { Someclass.dowork (success: ..., failure: ...}
Let task59 = { Someclass.dowork (success: task60, failure: ... }
...
Let task0 = { Someclass.dowork (success: task1, failure: ... }
Task0()
```

There’s absolutely no need to worry about performance due to use of closures.

Comment: isn't that essentially the same performance-wise, just more legible coz it is not as indented?

Comment: More legible is good, isn’t it? For more performance you’d need to find things that can be done in parallel.