# Arrays vs Maps for listing items that have a unique id

Tags: javascript, data-structures, array, map

I've been finding that for a lot of code I've been writing recently, it naively might look like this:

**Array approach:**

```
const options = [
   {
      id: 'red', 
      label: 'Red', 
      data: '#f00'
   }, 
   {
      id: 'blue', 
      label: 'Blue',
      data: '#00f' 
   }
];
```

And then something like, in say React context (but my question relates to programming generally):

```
return <select> 
    {options.map((v) => <option key = {v.id} value = {v.id}>{v.label}</option>}
</select>;
```

Now the problem with storing the list of options as an *array* is that if you ever need to look up an options object by just an id, you have to do a full scan over the array like:

```
function findOptionById(id) {
    return options.find((v) => v.id === id); 
}
```

Which doesn't seem particularly efficient (if this function is being called every render for example) and becomes particularly problematic when you have nested objects.

So the alternative:

**Map approach:**

```
const options = {
   red: {
      id: 'red', 
      label: 'Red', 
      data: '#f00'
   }, 
   blue: {
      id: 'blue', 
      label: 'Blue',
      data: '#00f' 
   }
};
```

Mapping over it:

```
Object.values(options).map((v) => <options key={v.id} value={v.id}>{v.label}</option>)
```

Finding an item in the list:

```
function findOptionById(id) {
    return options[id]
}
```

Faster lookup (I believe? or am I wrong in the context of javascript specifically?), and has the added advantage of enforcing some kind of ID uniqueness which is in my scenarios is always necessary.

**My question(s)**

It seems to me that in a scenario where 'You have a list of items, and they have some kind of unique key' then a map is always (or usually) advantageous to use.

However, from a code readability and 'the data structures make sense' POV, using arrays seems more intuitive.

That is for example, if I am creating a RadioList component and I'm saying 'it has an `options` property which is a list of items containing id, label, and data', then declaring this type as an array it's a lot more obvious to the user what the meaning of this property is.

Is there some kind of term or concept in software engineering that considers when an array should be used vs a map?

**Edit:** Although I've mentioned performance, it's not really my main concern. My main concern is around the ease of use of this list object, inserting, removing, looking up items etc.

Comment: Do you really see a huge difference in readability between those two data definitions? I mean, the only real difference seems to be the type of outermost brackets "[]" vs "{}".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is micro-optimisation important when coding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: I prefer a Map.  But it does seem that many web APIs return an Array.

Comment: @DocBrown The feedback I've received from other developers is that the first is more readable.

Answer (score 7):

The guiding principle for choosing a data structure should be its *usage*, not its members. If, as you say, you only need the items to render sequentially, an array is perfectly fine. If you need to lookup by a key, a map ia the right tool for the job. The fact that the item has an identifier isn't necessarily a factor.

That said:

- If you know you'll have a small number of items, the differences in performance might be  minimal, with a find operation not necessarily slower than a lookup.
- Factors like "code readability" can be subjective. I find maps to be extremely clear abd readable, probably due to using them for years. They convey intent easily.
- Maps have the added flexibility of being able to iterate over their values like an array in addition to indexed access. But they don't easily support keeping sorted order. Consider your use case carefully.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems to me that in a scenario where 'You have a list of items, and
> they have some kind of unique key' then a map is always (or usually)
> advantageous to use.
>
> However, from a code readability and 'the data structures make sense'
> POV, using arrays seems more intuitive.

Here, you already have your tradeoff. For a small number of items (e.g. when you draw select options in a user interface, which will never go into the 100s) performance will be practically irrelevant, whereas maintainability is the key.

However, if you are in a tight spot and actually *measure* a performance problem in your application, you can optimize the runtime by changing the data structure.

... and as Avner already stated: watch the order, as most maps don't keep it.

Comment: The ordering is a good point. If we're talking about a RadioList then order might matter.